# Selenium C# Firefox 22 - "silent save file" from web no longer working

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, nunit, selenium-webdriver

I'm doing tests of a WebPage using the selenium framework 2.33. the TestCase here should verify the download of a file.

The following code did work with Firefox 21 and older. Since the Update to FF 22, it is no longer working and I have not found out why.

I used it to save a tar.gz file, but txt or CSV files are also failing.

Setup driver:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true;
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP"));
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/xml, text/csv, text/plain, text/log, application/zlib, application/x-gzip, application/x-compressed, application/x-gtar, multipart/x-gzip, application/tgz, application/gnutar, application/x-tar");
profile.SetPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
IWebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Test:

```
webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com/downloadthis.txt");
```

Note:
in firefox 22, "about:config" the line "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk" with the given arguments is present. but despite this, the "save file" dialog pops up and the test is failing when it checks for the expected file at the saving location.

Does anyone have an idea or encountered this too?

edit: formatting

Comment: What's the actual MIME type shown from Fiddler? Your code works fine with csv for me, but not txt, I don't have Fiddler on my current machine, I need to check the actual MIMT type of the txt. http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt

Comment: Fiddler returned MIME type application/gzip for a .tar.gz file. Adding this to the options fixes the problem. firefox must have changed that to version 22 (old MIME was application/x-gzip). thank you, user1177636 for making my day a little bit more shiny!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, with the help of User user1177636 i came to the solution.

Firefox has changed the MIME type of .tar.gz files from FF 21 to 22

old: application/x-gzip
new: application/gzip

corrected the line in setup to:

```
profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/xml, text/csv, text/plain, text/log, application/zlib, application/x-gzip, application/x-compressed, application/x-gtar, multipart/x-gzip, application/tgz, application/gnutar, application/x-tar, application/gzip");
```

and it works again!

THX user1177636, i upvoted your comment (if that makes any sense) !

Answer (score 0):

You Can Download All Files (Eg: .xls, .csv, .pdf)

I also face same problem in my application:

I got solution using Robot in java

following code i write to download all file

```
                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                    //create robot object
                    Robot robot = new Robot();
                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                    //Click Down Arrow Key to select "Save File" Radio Button
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                    // Click 3 times Tab to take focus on "OK" Button
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                    //Click "Enter" Button to download file
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                    Thread.sleep(5000L);
                    System.out.println("Robot work Complete");
```